# Outlook getAccessTokenAsync errorcode:13003 on desktop

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to create an Outlook Add-in, but have a problem.

The Office library returned an error when I called `Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync` running on Outlook for the desktop.
But when I run this program on the web version (Office365) it is working without problems.

How to get `AccessToken` on Outlook for the desktop?

```
Office.initialize = function () {};

function testfunction(event) {
    Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function (result) {
        if (result.status === "succeeded") {
            //...
        }
    })
}
```

Error:

```
code:13003
message:The identity type of the user is not supported
```

Using Outlook 2016 (15.0.9126.2152) on Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://outlook2016(15.0.9126.2152)):

> #### 13001
>
> The user is not signed into Office. Your code should recall the `getAccessTokenAsync` method and pass the option `forceAddAccount: true` in the [options](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync#parameters) parameter. But don't do this more than once. The user may have decided not to sign-in.
>
> This error is never seen in Office Online. If the user's cookie expires, Office Online returns error 13006.

With Outlook, in particular, you will see this using an Outlook.com account (MSA isn't currently supported). You may also get a `13001` if you're using an on-prem Exchange Server without "modern auth" enabled. If this is the case, you will need to [enable modern auth](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32711.exchange-online-how-to-enable-your-tenant-for-modern-authentication.aspx) to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your desktop Outlook 2016(15.0.9126.2152) is the MSI (non-subscription) version. `getAccessTokenAsync` is not supported on that version.